# Compare values from one column in table A and another column in table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a NeedDate column in the expected output. I will compare the QtyShort from Table B with QtyReceive from table A.

In the expected output, if QtyShort = 0, NeedDate = MaltDueDate.

For the first row of table A, if 0 < QtyShort (in Table B) <= QtyReceive (=6), NeedDate = 10/08/2021 (DueDate from Table A).

If 6 < QtyShort <= 10 (QtyReceive), move to the second row, NeedDate = 10/22/2021 (DueDate from Table A).

If 10 < QtyShort <= 20 (QtyReceive), move to the third row, NeedDate = 02/01/2022 (DueDate from Table A).

If QtyShort > QtyReceive (=20), NeedDate = 09/09/9999.

This should continue in a loop until the last row on table B has been compared

How could we do this? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Table A

```
Item    DueDate      QtyReceive
A1      10/08/2021       6
A1      10/22/2021       10
A1      02/01/2022       20
```

Table B

```
Item    MatlDueDate    QtyShort
A1      06/01/2022         0
A1      06/02/2022         0
A1      06/03/2022         1
A1      06/04/2022         2
A1      06/05/2022         5
A1      06/06/2022         7
A1      06/07/2022         10
A1      06/08/2022         15  
A1      06/09/2022         25
```

Expected Output:

```
 Item    MatlDueDate    QtyShort     NeedDate
 A1      06/01/2022        0        06/01/2022
 A1      06/02/2022        0        06/02/2022
 A1      06/03/2022        1        10/08/2021
 A1      06/04/2022        2        10/08/2021
 A1      06/05/2022        5        10/08/2021
 A1      06/06/2022        7        10/22/2021
 A1      06/07/2022        10       10/22/2021
 A1      06/08/2022        15       02/01/2022 
 A1      06/09/2022        25       09/09/9999
```

Comment: And don't even think of a loop, this is SQL, you are looking for a set based approach.

Comment: Your description on the logic is not clear. What do you mean by `If 6 < QtyShort <= 10 (QtyReceive), move to the second row, NeedDate = 10/22/2021 (DueDate from Table A).` ? Can you explain further in detail ?

Comment: @Squirrel So for the first row the the Table A, QtyReceive = 6, if QtyShort in Table B <= 6, NeedDate = 10/08/2021 (The DueDate where QtyRecieve =6), If QtyShort in Table B > 6 and QtyShort < 10, for example 7 in the expected output, it will get 10/22/2021 for NeedDate, where QtyReceive = 10 in Table A. As long as QtyReceive > QtyShort, we always get the Date from DueDate (Table A) for NeedDate Column. Otherwise, it will return 09/09/9999.

Comment: @DaleK Thank you for your comment. I'm reading a set based approach in SQL to understand what you're saying. I'm trying to get an idea to write the code.

Comment: For the `QtyShort` , don't it need to be cumulative ? like `MatlDueDate 06/07/2022 QtyShort 10`, total `QtyShort` is `25 (1+2+5+7+10)`, so you need all 3 receive lines `36 (6 + 10 + 20)` to meet the `QtyShort` of `25`. Is this the logic ?

Comment: @Squirrel I already calculated Running Total of QtyShort using Windows Function. For this case, we need to compare every QtyShort to QtyReceive. We compare the first row of QtyReceive first, if QtyShort < QtyReceive (=6), get the DueDate of the first row. If QtyShort > 6, we need QtyReceive = 10 right? -> Get the DueDate of the second row in table A. QtyShort >10, get duedate of the third row of table A

Comment: @DaleK Thank you for your feedback. It will be more complicated if I give you full details of my work on this project. It must be longer than 3 pages to explain everything in detail. To me, it's too big and complicated (maybe easier for you). The question I asked was summarized by some basic numbers so other people can easily understand it. I love the way Squirrel resolves a problem. Simply focus on the question -> get more information -> corporate and generate the best solution. I wish I could do something to thank Squirrel.

Comment: @DaleK I will do that in the next question. I'm sorry for not providing my attempted work. This is my first question on StackOverflow and I'm still learning feedback from community like yours. Thanks again DaleK for caring about me. Otherwise, you already ignored my question <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OUTER APPLY()` operator to find the minimum `DueDate` from `TableA` that is able to fulfill the `QtyShort`

```
select b.Item, b.MatlDueDate, b.QtyShort,
       NeedDate = case when b.QtyShort = 0
                       then b.MatlDueDate
                       else isnull(a.DueDate, '9999-09-09')
                       end
from   TableB b
       outer apply
       (
           select DueDate = min(a.DueDate)
           from   TableA a
           where  a.Item = b.Item
           and    a.QtyReceive >= b.QtyShort
       ) a
```

Result:

| Item | MatlDueDate | QtyShort | NeedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2022-06-01 | 0 | 2022-06-01 |
| A1 | 2022-06-02 | 0 | 2022-06-02 |
| A1 | 2022-06-03 | 1 | 2021-10-08 |
| A1 | 2022-06-04 | 2 | 2021-10-08 |
| A1 | 2022-06-05 | 5 | 2021-10-08 |
| A1 | 2022-06-06 | 7 | 2021-10-22 |
| A1 | 2022-06-07 | 10 | 2021-10-22 |
| A1 | 2022-06-08 | 15 | 2022-02-01 |
| A1 | 2022-06-09 | 25 | 9999-09-09 |

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3faec929fc03214fbc4a3478fdff12d4)

Comment: Thank you for your best answer. It works like charm and perfectly solves my issue. Now I understand the logic behind your codes and apply it to my project. I really appreciate your help!